# change in permalink (and in at.access file because of it) causes no images to work in a wordpress site

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

In a specific WordPress site,
I've changed the site link structure (`Permalink`) and then have been asked to keep the system automatically changes up or change file permissions in `Ht.access` file, can not remember exactly what was written. But I did not because I did not know how.

In short, suddenly the pictures on the site stopped working, although all of the pictures are still in the uploads folder.

With more programmers we found this link on the network but not yet the solution: https://www.google.co.il/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=gDMIVqi-MOyH8Qfe1Yu4CA#safe=active&q=wp-content%2Fuploads+image+404

What is strange, is that when disabling the file - the images still don't work.
and I have a couple of `redirect plugins`.

Thanks in advance,
Only together we will succeed.

Comment: "and i have a couple of redirect plugins" .. delete them. Include a new .htaccess and refresh your database. redirect plugins are the hell in person. Can you edit your post and write your website with this issue?

Comment: The site is a restricted one, then no. But thank you very much, I'll try what you offered and will update. Thank you!

Comment: Okay. Maybe the permissions are changed. Do you checked that? If you use the Firefox AddOn 'firebug' you can see why the images are not loading.

Comment: Disable some redirect plugins and check properly if your permalink work